# Allocating a large array on the stack [C]

Tags: compiler-construction, stack, elf

perhaps there's already an answer to this, but I couldn't find it.

Suppose I have 2 programs as followed:

Prog.A:

```
int main (void) {
    int big[100];
    printf("%lu\n", sizeof(big));
    return 0;
}
```

Prog.B:

```
int main (void) {
    int big[100000000];
    printf("%lu\n", sizeof(big));
    return 0;
}
```

After compiling both programs, I see no difference between the elfs sizes.
When hex dumping both files, I see they both finish by address 0x00003e6c.

This is a bit weird because I was sure that when allocating arrays on the stack (statically), the compiler will write code to reserve that space, however I see no difference in files size.
(Prog.B allocated a larger array, thus I expected the compiler to reserve more space, which will eventually result in a larger elf size).

Hope my question even makes sense.

Comment: Since you don't actually use `big` for anything, an optimising compiler will probably eliminate it. (The size can be computed without actually allocating the storage.) Anyway, it's very unlikely that the stack will be allocated statically, although I suppose it's not impossible.

Comment: I have also tried to use volatile, and add some reads and writes further on of BIG array in order to avoid the compiler's optimizations. After doing so, I still experience some weird stuff, and now my ELF file of the larger file is even slighter in weight than the other program.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say what platform you are on. On the vast majority of common platforms, stack is *not* allocated statically. Rather, the stack reservation is simply decrementing the stack pointer (which requires the same amount of code whether you are reserving 1 byte of 40,000,000), so it's *not at all* surprising that the binary size is the same.

To see what's going on, run `objdump -d` on ProgA and ProgB and compare the output.

Comment: I am on Linux distribution platform. Indeed, after checking the objdump -d, I see that the main change is the fact that in progA (smaller array) we sub 0x30 from %rsp, when in progB, we sub 0x619A0. Your answer makes perfect sense now. Thanks a lot